# How to set new property in user metadata?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to set some property in user metadata. I'm trying to do this using https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens and then https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#update_user-specific_metadata_in.

Probably I'm doing something wrong, because it's not working.  If I do this like in this article, and then call auth().listUsers to get the users data, 'metadata' has only default properties: creationTime and lastSignInTime, but without the new property revokeTime, any idea?

Edit:

My revoke function:

```
export const revokeUsersToken = functions.https.onCall(async (req, res) => {
  const admin = await import('firebase-admin');

  if (!isRevokeUsersTokenInitialized) {
    admin.initializeApp();
    isRevokeUsersTokenInitialized = true;
  }

  return admin
    .auth()
    .revokeRefreshTokens(req.uid)
    .then(() => {
      return admin.auth().getUser(req.uid);
    })
    .then(userRecord => {
      return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime as string).getTime() / 1000;
    })
    .then(timestamp => {
      const metadataRef = admin.database().ref('metadata/' + req.uid);

      metadataRef.set({ revokeTime: timestamp }).then((x) => {
        return `Database updated successfully: ${x}`;
      }).catch(error => {
        return `Error: ${error}`;
      });
    });
});
```

Then, when I try to get all users:

```
export const getListUsers = functions.https.onCall(async (req, res) => {
  const admin = await import('firebase-admin');

  if (!isGetListUsersInitialized) {
    admin.initializeApp();
    isGetListUsersInitialized = true;
  }
  const maxResults = 100; // optional arg.

  return admin
    .auth()
    .listUsers(maxResults)
    .then(userRecords => {
      return userRecords.users.map(user => {
        const {
          passwordHash,
          passwordSalt,
          phoneNumber,
          photoURL,
          providerData,
          tokensValidAfterTime,
          customClaims,
          ...us
        } = user;
        return {
          ...us,
          role: customClaims && customClaims.hasOwnProperty('role') ? (customClaims as any).role : null
        };
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

and if I get this users list there is not info about new metadata property

Comment: Better? Sorry but most of this code is in firebase guide ;-)

Comment: I'm not clear about what the problem is. What line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do? What does it do? And what did you expect?

Comment: I'm talk about this -> metadataRef.set({ revokeTime: timestamp }).

It shouldn't set new property ('revokeTime') to the user metadata? And if I call .auth().listUsers I shoudn't see that new property into 'userRecords ' response?

Comment: You're writing a `revokeTime` to the database, which has nothing to do with the Firebase authentication record for that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked describes how to revoke access for a user to the database, without waiting for that user's ID token to expire. To accomplish this, it uses two products: Firebase Authentication, and Firebase Realtime Database.

But the two products have no knowledge of each other, so the `revokeTime` you write to the database won't show up in the user's authentication record.

Comment: yeah, make sense, thx. I will try to do it in a different way.